# echo just json_encode to json from php

Tags: php, json, soap

-I have a soap code to send sms from site in send.php file

```
$soapClientObj = new SoapClient("http://xxx/Post/Send.asmx?wsdl");
$parameters['username'] = "xxx";
$parameters['password'] = "xxx";
$parameters['to'] = "xxx";
$parameters['text'] = "xxx";
print_r($soapClientObj->SendSms($parameters));
```

-and a `.js` file that send some data and get some data from index.php file

-and index.php file:

```
...
echo json_encode(array('r' => $numid,'m' => 'xxx'));
sndsms($text,array("$mobilenumber")); //function in send.php
...
```

now i call index.php, and just want to send below code from index.php

```
json_encode(array('r' => '0','m' => '???'));
```

but the string that sending every time in `json_encode(array('r' => '0','m' => '???'));`  + return value of `print_r($soapClientObj->SendSms($parameters));` in send.php
how can i send just json_encode?

Comment: So you call the send.php from another site (via HTTP i guess) and the `json_encode` is also in your send.php right? and you problem is what?

Comment: Please explain it clearly.

Comment: @AndreschSerj no json_encode is in index.php, soap is in send.php, and json_encode send to a js file

Comment: Sorry but this all is still quite hard to understand. Please explain in detail what file calls what other file and how (HTTP / include) and where you get outputs, explain what outputs you expect and what it is you get.

Comment: @AndreschSerj read again ;-)

Comment: @DineshBabu read again ;-)

Comment: So the problem is your print_r in your send SMS method right? Because that produces an output when you send an SMS and you do nt want that output right?

Comment: @hamidso consider accepting my answer to prevent this question from getting more unneeded attention, or if my answer didn't solve your problem, use the comments section to ask for further detail. Or, since this question will least likely be of much help for anyone in the future, consider deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you call your sms method, defined in your send.php and that returns an output, due to your print_r statement.
Now you want to send the SMS but not produce the outpur in your index.php but rather just output the results of your json_encode statement.

Considering this, you probably want to wrap your send.php code in a function and have it return a string, rather than outpout it to the output buffer.

```
function sendSMS ($text, $parameters) {
  $soapClientObj = new SoapClient("http://example.org/Post/Send.asmx?wsdl");
  $parameters['username'] = "xxx"; 
  $parameters['password'] = "xxx";
  $parameters['to']       = "xxx";
  $parameters['text']     = $text;
  return $soapClientObj->SendSms($parameters);
}
```

Now you can either just call it like this

```
sendSMS($text,array("$mobilenumber"));
```

or print it like before:

```
print_r(sendSMS($text,array("$mobilenumber")));
```

Now in your index.php you want to do this:

```
echo json_encode(array('r' => $numid,'m' => 'xxx'));
sendSMS($text,array("$mobilenumber"));
```

Comment: your code return `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\send.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
{"r":0,"m":"XXXX"}`  
same my code but i want just `{"r":0,"m":"XXXX"}`

Comment: @hamidso What is line 16?

Comment: `return $soapClientObj->SendSms($parameters);`

Comment: So in that line, an array get's converted to a string. This could mean that a) this line was faulty to begin with because it needs a string, not an array in `$parameters` or b) your error is somewhere else and we need more context :(